# HTML to DITA through perl

Tags: html, perl, dita

I am attempting to convert DOCX to DITA topics through an intermediate HTML step.

Now, with simple substitutions either in 'sed' or 'emacs' or 'vi', I can do most of the changes, but not certain types. For that I may need Perl or Python. Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

From:

```
<h1> Head 1 </H1>
  <body> 
  </body>


 <h2>Sub Head 1 </h2>
  <body>
  </body>


  <h3>SubSub Head 1 </h3>
   <body> 
   </body>

 <h2>Sub Head 2 </h2>
 <body> 
 </body>

<h1>Head 2 </h1>
<body> 
</body>
```

To:

```
<topic><title> Head 1 </title>
  <body> 
  </body>

 <topic><title> Sub Head 1 </title>
  <body>
  </body>

  <topic><title> SubSub Head 1 </title>
   <body> 
   </body>
  </topic>
 </topic>

 <topic><title> Sub Head 2 </title>
 <body> 
 </body>
 </topic>
</topic>

<topic><title> Head 2 </title>
<body> 
</body>
</topic>
```

The part I have trouble with is the part where I need to place the  tags for nested topics (and yes, I do have nested topics; my needs are somewhat unique since I am migrating existing documents). If someone can suggest a perl snippet (or a pointer to one similar) for this (placement of  tags on a per  tag basis), I can build my script around it.

Thanks in advance for looking and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

That's the kind of processing I often use [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig) for.

The `wrap_children` method is designed just for this: it lets you define a regexp-like expression that will be wrapped in an element. See the example below and the docs for more:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 1;

use XML::Twig;

# reads the DATA section, the input doc first, then the expected result
my( $in, $expected)= do{ local $/="\n\n"; <DATA>}; 

my $t=XML::Twig->new->parse( $in);
my $root= $t->root;

# that's where the wrapping occurs, form inside out
$root->wrap_children( '<h3><body>',                   topic => { level => 3 });
$root->wrap_children( '<h2><body><topic level="3">*', topic => { level => 2 });
$root->wrap_children( '<h1><body><topic level="2">*', topic => { level => 1 });

# now we cleanup: the levels are not used any more
foreach my $to ($t->descendants( 'topic'))
  { $to->del_att( 'level'); }

# the wrapping will have generated tons of additional id's, 
# you may not need this if your elements had id's before the wrapping
foreach my $to ($t->descendants( 'topic|body|h1|h2|h3'))  
  { $to->del_att( 'id'); }

# now we can deal with titles
foreach my $h  ($t->descendants( 'h1|h2|h3')) { $h->set_tag( 'title'); }

# how did we do?
is( $t->sprint( pretty_print => 'indented'), $expected, 'just one test');

__DATA__
<doc>
  <h1> Head 1 </h1>
    <body></body>
  <h2> Sub Head 1 </h2>
    <body></body>
  <h3> SubSub Head 1 </h3>
    <body></body>
  <h2> Sub Head 2 </h2>
    <body></body>
  <h1> Head 2 </h1>
    <body></body>
</doc>

<doc>
  <topic>
    <title> Head 1 </title>
    <body></body>
    <topic>
      <title> Sub Head 1 </title>
      <body></body>
      <topic>
        <title> SubSub Head 1 </title>
        <body></body>
      </topic>
    </topic>
    <topic>
      <title> Sub Head 2 </title>
      <body></body>
    </topic>
  </topic>
  <topic>
    <title> Head 2 </title>
    <body></body>
  </topic>
</doc>
```

Comment: Mirod: many thanks for your response. But I keep getting this:

wrong condition 'topic|body|h1|h2|h3' at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/XML/Twig.pm line 2463
# Looks like your test died before it could output anything.

This is perl, v5.8.5 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Comment: You may need a more recent version of the module (and of Perl, 5.8.5? How old is this?)

Comment: The File datestamp says 2007. But I was able to work around it by removing the id/setting title attributes one by one instead of 'h1|h2|h3'. So this works out for me. Struggling with prettyprint, but this may also be because of an older Perl (Not administrator on this domain). So, again, many thanks for the solution.

Comment: OK - I just figured out one problem. The <body> tags don't exist in source HTML - nothing to distinguish the block from one <h> to the next, actually. The <topic></topic> simply need to cling to subsequent declarations of <h1>, <h2>, etc. I changed the wrap_children to remove the <body> but the wrapping depends on the <body> tags. So while the method works for the example, I had the requirement wrong in the first place :-/. Many thanks, either case, Mirod.